# Use cy.session across multiple tests in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-session

In latest version of Cypress Cookie preserve is deprecated so I wish to us cy.session. However I can't get this to work across multiple tests as cy.session needs to be inside a test 'it', example of how my tests are currently set up.

```
    beforeEach(() => {
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
    preserve: /somecookie|someOtherCookie|AnotherCookie/
    })
   it('Navigate to URL', () => {
        performance.NavigateToUrl(URL);
    });

    it('Login - Username/Pass', () => {
        performance.LoginUserPass();
    });        
    it('Navigate Order Page', () => {
        performance.Orderpage();
    });
     //And so on............
```

Any help and suggestions welcome as i don't really want to rewrite the test structure as i create a report on it current output/design.

for the session to be kept across all tests

Answer (score 6):

With recent changes, Cypress are trying to "enforce" test isolation more, and you are going against their best practice by having dependency across the different `it()` blocks.

A better approach would be to structure according to context

```js
context('before logging in', () => {

   it('Can navigate to home page', () => {
     ...
   })

   it('Can log in', () => {
     ...
   })  
})

context('after logging in', () => {

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.session('login', () => {
      // do login via cy.request()
      // preserve all browser login data such as cookies, localstorage
    })
  })

  it('Can use order page', () => {
    ...
  })
})
```

---

**Test isolation flag**

There is a note on the `cy.session()` page that indicates you can turn off test isolation, but the paragraphs are a bit vague IMO

> The page is cleared before setup when testIsolation is enabled and is not cleared when testIsolation is disabled.
>
> Cookies, local storage and session storage in all domains are always cleared before setup runs, regardless of the testIsolation configuration.

So, it's worth trying with setting `testIsolation: false` - but don't call `cy.session()` at all.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could use the cy.session with the callback function in a `before` hook with both the visit and login methods:

```
const sessionId = 'Login with valid credentials'

before(() => {
  cy.session(sessionId, () => {
    performance.NavigateToUrl(URL)
    performance.LoginUserPass()
  })
})
```

Then restore the session and visit the page again in a `beforeEach` hook.

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.session(sessionId)
  performance.NavigateToUrl(URL)
})

it('Navigate Order Page', () => {
  performance.Orderpage();
})
//And so on............
```

Comment: Hi, i tried that before posting and it didn't work, thanks for reply though

Comment: I've tried this as well, does not work. See my related question here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77647010/how-do-we-cache-and-restore-cookies-in-cypress-with-cy-session